# Extra Customer Functionality in Magento

Tags: magento, module

I am building a Magento extension, in which I need to have the following three functionalities:-

1. Each product in my Magento store will have the option to upload multiple image files, and it differs product-to-product. Some specific products may have 4 & some 3 & some will have 2 image files to be uploaded. But these files can only be uploaded by a registered customer only when he has paid the order first.
2. After the order has been paid, customer can login into his account & see the order items in his "My Orders" section. In that section, he will be provided with options to upload files based on the product Sku. This is because some product Sku will have 4 file upload options available & some will have 3 & some 2 (as said in the last point).
3. The admin can view those files in either the Customer's details or the Sales details.

Can anybody please highlight what needs to be done in order to extend the Magento functionality without even touching the core Magento code.

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, did this result in an extension somewhere? I'm looking for the same functionality :)

Comment: @ArnoTeigseth - Hi Arno, yes it did result in an extension, but it was prepared exclusively for a client.  If you want to have something like this as an extension, I would suggest you to get in touch with InSync Tech-Fin Solutions.
Facebook - https://www.facebook.com/InSyncSolutions
Twitter - compusubha

Comment: Thanks, Knowledge Craving. However after some more googling I found this post that basically did what I wanted, although it does give a full solution to OPs requirements: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4396/image-upload-by-customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create new attribute for product - like media gallery.
2. Create model for this attribute, like product media gallery.
3. Create interface in customer section, where customer can upload images to the product.
4. Create interface in admin section, where shop manager can approve images.

Create new attribute media gallery like this in sql installer of your module.

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'media_gallery',  array(
        'group'         => 'Images',
        'label'         => 'Media Gallery',
        'input'         => 'gallery',
        'backend'       => 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_media',
        'class'         => '',
        'global'        => true,
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false
    )
);
```

You may use existing model with tables and add new values to the table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value and change media gallery model. That may work with new fucntinality or create standalone functionality.

Create new model like : Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media, extend it add "approved by", "uploaded by" and other parameters what you need.

Key features. 
Allow customer to add images to the product.
Show images gallery with moderation. 
Allow shop manager accept or decline new images.

Comment: simply great. Just few more things, to know. 1. from where can i get some details about the parameters supported by "addAttribute()" method? 2. can you please provide me more details about how to create nice interface using the magento interface class?

Comment: @Knowledge Craving You should create interface itself. For admin you may use Grid component and Form. For installer class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup see this class.

Comment: Hi there, did this result in an extension somewhere? I'm looking for the same functionality :)